# QMessageBox inside of a stacked widget

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, widget, messagebox

I am working in QT and have a QStackedWidget and a button on level 0 of the stacked widget. This button makes a messagebox appear on level 1 of the stacked widget. Is there a way to make the messagebox appear regardless of which level of the stacked widget i am currently looking at? So if a message box appears at level 1, is there a way so that it shows up regardless of which level of the QStackedWidget I am looking at?

Comment: How are you instantiating the message box?

Comment: QMessageBox msgBox(NULL);



I am setting values for fields on the message box after it is instantiated. I end by calling msgBox.exec();

Answer (score 1):

Make the `QMessageBox` parentless.  Then it should pop up above everything.

Comment: I did this and the messagebox is still appearing at level 1. It is not appearing at the top level of 0.

Comment: Is your code for the message box even running if you are not at that level?  Try putting a `qDebug` statement where you want the QMessage box to see if you are even reaching that line of code.

Comment: Also you could try one of the static pop ups that QMessage box has like `QMessageBox::about` .